# MongoDb Aggregate Total Count Before Grouping

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation pipeline that groups objects and holds count for some specific field for grouped objects. You can reproduce the problem here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/2DGaiQDYDBP .

The schema is like this;

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "63ce93ffb6e06322db59fdc0"
    },
    "fruit": "apple",
    "source": "tree",
    "is_fruit_important": "true"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "63ce93ffb6e06322db59fdc1"
    },
    "fruit": "orange",
    "source": "tree",
    "is_fruit_important": "false"
  },
]
```

and the current query groups fruits by the source, and holds the count of important fruits for every group. After applying aggregation I get something like this after query:

```
[
  {
    "count": {
      "number_of_important_fruits": 1
    },
    "objects": [
      {
        "fruit": "apple",
        "id": "63ce93ffb6e06322db59fdc0",
        "is_fruit_important": "true",
        "source": "tree"
      },
      {
        "fruit": "orange",
        "id": "63ce93ffb6e06322db59fdc1",
        "is_fruit_important": "false",
        "source": "tree"
      }
    ],
    "source": {
      "source-of": "tree"
    }
  }
]
```

Is there a way to put the **number of all fruits** in the database to the response object. For example like this:

```
  {
    "total-count": 2,
    "result": [
      {
        "count": {
          "number_of_important_fruits": 1
        },
        "objects": [
          {
            "fruit": "apple",
            "id": "63ce93ffb6e06322db59fdc0",
            "is_fruit_important": "true",
            "source": "tree"
          },
          {
            "fruit": "orange",
            "id": "63ce93ffb6e06322db59fdc1",
            "is_fruit_important": "false",
            "source": "tree"
          }
        ],
        "source": {
          "source-of": "tree"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

They can be handled in separate aggregation pipelines but that's what I would not like to implement. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add one additional group stage just before the final $project, using `$sum` with `$size` for a total count, or add up the important counts for a total important count.

```
  {$group: {
      _id: null,
      result: {$push: "$$ROOT"},
      "count_total": {$sum: {$size: "$objects"}},
      "count_important": {$sum: "$count.number_of_important_fruits"}
  }},
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mocYDXQjHCF)

Comment: That was the final precious touch! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a `$facet` stage to push all your results into `result`. Then perform a `$size` on `result` to get `total-count`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  ...,
  {
    "$facet": {
      "result": [],
      "total-important-count": [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            cnt: {
              $sum: "$count.number_of_important_fruits"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "total-count": {
        $size: "$result"
      },
      "total-important-count": {
        $first: "$total-important-count.cnt"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/K_9M8Y5V6Wt)

Comment: There's a gotcha here. $facet is a nice solution but I have to get the count of all the fruits before grouping not after grouping. There are 4 fruits in the database here, but the total count is 2 in the example, because it counted the number after grouping.

Comment: @FatihErsoy Actually, `$facet` is only a good solution for simple cases but it may not scale for a large number of results. @Joe's answer would be a better one. I am just updating and keeping the answer to demo `$facet` as an alternative.

Comment: Hey @ray, I have found an answer with $facet also! While trying, if we put $facet in the beginning, it works because we are able to reach data before grouping. If you are interested, please see the playground link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/9nlyg_xB8QM

Comment: I have processed data a bit and updated the link.

Comment: @FatihErsoy That's nice and neat work. My main concern for `$facet` is that if we have many results, we might exceed [16MB document size limitation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-BSON-Document-Size). But if we know beforehand our result set is a small one, `$facet` is good for its simplicity. One of the common use cases for `$facet` is pagination as we limit our results by pageSize and we want to include some meta fields like page number and total counts etc.

Comment: Yes that's true. The origin of question was also coming from pagination, where I needed the data count before the "limit". I have a "$match" pipe where I make the document very small in the original pipeline so document size is not a problem for my case. Thank you for your effort and explanations!